# Do I need an HTML file for every single page on my website?

Tags: html, web

Say I have a product website, like Amazon (this is not the case, but it will help me explain my point), and I have a URL for every single product (such as with Amazon)...
Do I need to copy-paste and modify an HTML file for every single individual product page, or is there a way to use a "model" on which I can base all my other pages without recopying the whole code and modifying a few things in each?
I've just started learning HTML and web development, so bare with me if I'm asking a stupid question.
It just seems odd to me that a million-page website should host a million+ individual, nearly identical, HTML files.

Thank you very much in advance.

P.S. I'm using Amazon's brand name as an example here, and am not affiliated with anything related to it. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: You can, but most sites it is a dynamic back end that spits out HTML.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for your fast response.  So, of what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), a "dynamic backend" generates HTML from a given algorithm without having to actually create a concrete page... So are there any available easy-to-use web apps for beginners that can do this? Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to use this type of technology for beginners? Thanks again for your response. :)

Comment: There are a billion frameworks out there.

Comment: depends on your language... PHP? Node? Python?

Comment: @S. Wasta Well... I started learning C ANSI... Is that possible? Otherwise, I guess I could learn Python, since I've been told that it's quite easy to use.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need an HTML file for every single page on your website. While you could do that, it is becomes very infeasible to manage the bigger your site becomes. On most websites you would have the following components:

1. A front end - consists of HTML code and usually some sort of template engine with placeholders for your data
2. A backend - consists of your data store (usually a database).

There will also usually be some form of API and/or middleware between your front end and backend.

If you go to https://example.com/myproductid in your browser, your computer will send that request to the web server. The web server will then retrieve your data, load it into the correct template, and serve the page to you.

In traditional HTML and PHP only websites, you would have to reload the entire page each time you went to a new product. However, you can instead use a technique called Ajax to only update certain parts of a web page rather than reloading the entire page. That way you can just update the text, images, and links that are specific to the product, and the rest of the page would stay the same. (Note: Ajax originally used XML, modern implementations usually use JSON).

Ultimately, you will want to learn some JavaScript and then start looking into various web frameworks or libraries such as ReactJS.

Comment: There you go. This is what I call a complete and concise answer. Thank you so much... Thank you for the details on Ajax; it answers so many of my questions. Now you say that Ajax nowadays uses JSON, but can I still use XML? What are the disadvantages?.. Also you talk about frameworks. I had done some research and was really enthusiast to find out that there are a few C++ frameworks out there (e.g. Wt, CppCMS)... Is this the worst idea ever, given that I'm a (very) beginner, or is it worth looking into? Thanks again. :)

Comment: @G-Power Yes, you are still able to use XML if you would like, but why would you want to? JSON is much easier to work with in nearly all cases. Why are you excited about the C++ frameworks specifically? If you are just starting out and do not know C++ then you would probably be able to get something up and running a lot faster with a JavaScript framework (such as ReactJS). Everyone is going to have their own opinions about what is best though. Choose what you think is best for you and branch out from there. Look into `full stack` development.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was only asking about XML by curiosity and, now that you tell me that JSON is simpler and more convenient to use, that's what I would go for since I don't know any XML yet anyway. The reason why I'm excited about C++ frameworks is that I've learned a fair bit of C and I'm more interested in developing apps than websites. Also I've heard that C++ is quite powerful and flexible, even though it's proven to be a harder-than-average-to-learn language. Am I getting this right? Thanks for you response. :)

Comment: @G-Power If your want to focus on developing apps more than websites why are you wanting to use C++? Neither Android nor iOS platforms support apps fully written in C++. Yes, you can add some modules written in C++, but not the entire app. If you are looking at developing the same app for both Android and iOS platforms then you can look at a cross-platform development library such as React Native. If you learn React Native for mobile it would be easy to switch to ReactJS for the web as they are very similar JavaScript libraries. Also, C and C++ are quite different.

Comment: Excuse me for my lack of precision... What I meant was PC apps, more specifically. I have really no interest in programming phone apps for now. In my opinion, phones should be used to call each other.  But I didn't know C and C++ were that different... I might start investing time into learning JS as well, then. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any frameworks for C. Thank you for letting me know about the difference between C and C++. I wasn't aware it was that significant, but knowing so will save me some time and effort. 

Comment: @G-Power I would put the challenge to you that you are perhaps being a bit too obstinate in how you choose to define things. Mobile devices include phones and many other tools as well, so they are not just phones. I'm sure you know this, but for whatever reason you are wanting to be stubborn about something related to this area. Attitudes like this can make you crotchety later in life, so best to avoid them. As for C, there are a number of C libraries and frameworks depending what you want to do. Though I would encourage you to expand your horizons and try some other languages as well.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly true. Excuse me for quickness at categorising things. My attitude is something I've been working on for a while now. ;) I didn't know there were C frameworks... Can you refer me to me to any in particular, or to a resource where I can find a list of them? That would be very appreciated.

Comment: Two examples of C frameworks/libraries include Kore and Onion (found with Google). However, it all depends on how you define framework and what exactly you are looking for in one. Is there a reason you would prefer to develop a desktop app rather than a web-based app? In most cases, web-based applications are a lot easier to create, manage, and maintain. You also don't have to worry about whether your clients having the proper software or operating system on their computer. So, as long as they have a web browser it should work for them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll look into those two examples you mentioned. That's great. :) For what regards my interest in building desktop apps, it's for other, more complex, projects that I would like to do in the future. Thank you again for helping me out with all my questions and sharing your knowledge. It's very appreciated. Bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Not you Can have only one page for all product, but you have to make it Dynamic.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you need an HTML document for your each webpage, like for Home page, contact us page you need different HTML documents

Comment: This is not quite right anymore. In the past when every website was static, this was the case. However now we can edit the pages dynamically with Javascript or other web frameworks so we can create "one page apps" which use only one (or a few) HTML pages which can display a variety of data based on the logic that was implemented in the framework/script.

Comment: @FedericoPettinella From a practical perspective there was never really a time when every website was static. Dynamic technologies predate HTML websites. CGI was used in the early days of the web, and there were other dynamic implementations before CGI came on the scene.